# How to read Bluetooth LE address of a peripheral?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

When a central, on iPad, scans and detects a peripheral, how can it read the Bluetooth LE address of the peripheral?

The `CBPeripheral` class does not have a property for 'address'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For privacy reasons the Bluetooth Address is hidden as a "UUID" (or NSUUID)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/translated_content/CBPeripheral.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CBPeripheral/identifier

If you really need to know a constant bluetooth address of a peripheral then program it into one of its characteristics or into the advertisement package as part of your unique manufacturer data field.

This require of course that you have asked BT SIG for a manufacturer id (and that you are the "manufacturer" of the peripheral) and that the peripheral uses Static Bluetooth address.